# Zero inflated poisson model fails to fit

Tags: r, poisson

Here's the data and set up:

```
library(fitdistrplus)
library(gamlss)

finalVector <- dput(finalVector)
c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 
2, 1, 4, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 4, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 
2, 1, 1, 4, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)

countFitPoisson <- fitdist(finalVector,"pois",  method = "mle", lower = 0)
countFitZeroPoisson <- fitdist(finalVector, 'ZIP', start = list( ##mu  = mean of poisson, sigma = prob(x = 0))
                                                           mu = as.numeric(countFitPoisson$estimate), 
                                                            sigma = as.numeric(as.numeric(countFitPoisson$estimate))
                                                          ), method = "mle", lower= 0)
```

The first call works successfully. The final says it failed to estimate and I'm not sure why. Thanks!

**Edit:**

Assuming I did the code correctly (not sure), then the only thing I can think of is that there are *not enough* zeros to fit the model?

Comment: It seems to work when you pad a few 0's (5) and change the starting parameters to something closer to the mle value (0.7, 0.05).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your data is not really zero-inflated, hence fitting the model does not lead to an improvement. Rather than using the `fitdistr` approach, I'm using `glm` and extended regression models below. All regression (sub-)models just use a constant (or intercept) without any real regressors, though. For visualization I use rootograms via the `countreg` package available from R-Forge (which contains the successor functions to the `pscl` count data regressions).

First, let's look at the Poisson fit:

```
(mp <- glm(finalVector ~ 1, family = poisson))
## Call:  glm(formula = finalVector ~ 1, family = poisson)
## 
## Coefficients:
## (Intercept)  
##      -0.284  
## 
## Degrees of Freedom: 181 Total (i.e. Null);  181 Residual
## Null Deviance:      200.2 
## Residual Deviance: 200.2        AIC: 418.3
```

This corresponds to a fitted mean of `exp(-0.284)`, i.e., about 0.753. This fits the data very well if you compare observed and fitted frequencies:

```
library("countreg")
rootogram(mp)
```

This shows that the fit for the counts 0, 1, 2 is essentially perfect and there are only small deviations for 3, 4, 5 but these frequencies are extremely low anyway. So judging from this it appears that no extension of the model is necessary.

[image: rootogram]

But to formally compare the model with others, one could consider a zero-inflated Poisson (as you tried) a hurdle Poisson or a negative binomial. The zero-inflated model yields:

```
(mzip <- zeroinfl(finalVector ~ 1 | 1, dist = "poisson"))
## Call:
## zeroinfl(formula = finalVector ~ 1 | 1, dist = "poisson")
## 
## Count model coefficients (poisson with log link):
## (Intercept)  
##     -0.2839  
## 
## Zero-inflation model coefficients (binomial with logit link):
## (Intercept)  
##      -9.151
```

Thus, the count mean is essentially identical to before and the probability of zero-inflation is essentially zero (`plogis(-9.151)` is about 0.01%).

The hurdle model works similarly but can use a zero-censored Poisson model for 0-vs-greater and a truncated Poisson for the positive counts. This is then also nested within the Poisson model and hence a Wald test can be carried easily out:

```
mhp <- hurdle(finalVector ~ 1 | 1, dist = "poisson", zero.dist = "poisson")
hurdletest(mhp)
## Wald test for hurdle models
## 
## Restrictions:
## count_((Intercept) - zero_(Intercept) = 0
## 
## Model 1: restricted model
## Model 2: finalVector ~ 1 | 1
## 
##   Res.Df Df Chisq Pr(>Chisq)
## 1    181                    
## 2    180  1 0.036     0.8495
```

This also clearly shows that there are no excess zeros and a simple Poisson model suffices.

As a final check one could also consider a negative binomial model:

```
(mnb <- glm.nb(finalVector ~ 1))
## Call:  glm.nb(formula = finalVector ~ 1, init.theta = 125.8922776, link = log)
## 
## Coefficients:
## (Intercept)  
##      -0.284  
## 
## Degrees of Freedom: 181 Total (i.e. Null);  181 Residual
## Null Deviance:      199.1 
## Residual Deviance: 199.1        AIC: 420.3
```

This has again virtually the same mean and a huge theta parameter that is close enough to infinity (= Poisson). Thus, overall the Poisson model is simply sufficient and there is no need for any of the extensions considered. The likelihoods are almost unchanged and the additional parameters (zero-inflation, zero-hurdle, theta-dispersion) do not yield any improvement:

```
AIC(mp, mzip, mhp, mnb)
##      df      AIC
## mp    1 418.2993
## mzip  2 420.2996
## mhp   2 420.2631
## mnb   2 420.2959
```

Comment: I completely agree with your analysis -- but I wonder should the package not return a regular poisson model then rather than crash?

Comment: It does not "crash" but terminates with a sufficiently informative error: sigma becomes 0 but must be between 0 and 1. This indicates a degenerate model and hence an error is in order. The `zeroinfl` function avoids this by using a logit link so that the probability has to be strictly between 0 and 1. But you still see the degeneration because an intercept of -9.2 on the logit scale is already pretty close to -Infinity. Using `reltol = 1e-12` would lead to -11.7 already and lower `reltol` values also lead to a failure to converge...